# Spring application events without extending ApplicationEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-principles, hexagonal-architecture

Is there any way to define custom application events without extending `ApplicationEvent`?
We are having submodules based on ports and adapters principle, `domain` module not having any any external dependencies like `spring-context`. And `application` module can have Spring dependency and `EventListener` and `EventPublisher` classes.

Event classes seems domain specific, and should be defined independent of any framework. But with current Spring's approach for defining events, we have to depend on `spring-context`. Any alternatives?

Comment: You don't need to extend that class, your knowledge is dated. This has been the case since Spring 4.2, before that version it was required, if you use that or newer versions you can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can publish whatever you like with the [`ApplicationEventPublisher`]. This has been the case since Spring 4.2 which saw the introduction of `@EventListener`. Since then you don't need to extend `ApplicationEvent` anymore.

Hence your knowledge was/is outdated.